# OMS and Azure Functions Link

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-oms

We are trying to connect Azure Functions with OMS. So far, we could not find any direct link with OMS and Azure Function. Is it correct to assume that?

One workaround we found is to log Azure Function data to Application Insights and connect the Application Insight with OMS. We want to do this via ARM Template or PowerShell. What is the correct approach to do this? It would be real help if anybody has any sample script for this.

We've tried the below steps but it did not work.

1. Added 'ApplicationInsight' solution through Set-AzureRmOperationalInsightsIntelligencePack powershell command but it still requires more configuration to link the application insights with OMS. We could not find any command to do that.
2. Tried 'Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions' type in ARM template but it did not work.

We are stuck with this and it is becoming a showstopper issue. Can anyone please help us out?

Comment: For a function app to send data to Application Insights, it needs to know the instrumentation key of an Application Insights resource. The key has to be provided in an app setting named APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY. check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#enable-app-insights-integration

Comment: It is already there. Function app is already sending telemetry to Application Insight. Objective is to connect the application insight with OMS. We need help there ...